# Group Action determined by equations

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ a group, $X$ a set. An action of $G$ on $X$ is given by a mapping $(g,x) \to g \cdot x$, which satisfies $g \cdot (h \cdot x) = (gh) \cdot x$ and $e_G \cdot x = x$.
In other words, to determine an action one must know how every element of the group acts on every element of the set.

> Can an action be determined by means other then giving explicitly the
>   action of every element of $G$ on every element of $X$?

What if I have several equations (depending on elements of X and G, and the action of G) that give some information of the action - when are the equations strong enough so they induce an action on the entire set? Furthermore, are there cases where I can fully recover the action?

For example, suppose that $X$ is a (given) set of elements of a field extension $K/k$, and $G \subseteq Gal(K / k)$. We would like to extend that action of $G$ to $K(X)$, such that the extended action satisfies several equations.

Is there any theory in mathematics that asks and answers this sort of questions?

Comment: You only need to specify the action for a set of generators of $G$, because that enables you to calculate it for all elements of $G$.

Comment: Remember that giving an action of $G$ on $X$ is equivalent to give a group morphism from $G$ to $Bij(X)$ (the set of bijections of $X$). Now, a morphism is only defined by the images of the generators of $G$ (by the way if you have a set of relations for a particular set of generators of $G$ then you have conditions to know if some particular images of the generators of $G$ define an action or not).

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_n$ denote the free group of rank $n$. You can characterise the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(F_2)$ on $F_2$ by an equation as follows:

> **Theorem** (Theorem 3.9, Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, Combinatorial group theory, 1975 (2nd Ed.))
>
> A map $f: a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto y$, where $x, y\in F_2$, is an automorphism of $F_2$ if and only if there exists an element $z\in F_2$ such that $$z^{-1}[x, y]z=[a, b]~\text{or}~z^{-1}[x, y]z=[a, b]^{-1}.$$

Hence, automorphisms somehow correspond to solutions to the equations $z^{-1}[x, y]z=[a, b]^{\pm1}$. On the other hand, automorphisms of $F_n$ for $n>2$ cannot be described in this way. In fact, I understand that they cannot be characterised precisely using first-order sentences (although I cannot find a reference for this).